# Can't view keys of hdf5 file after opening it with 'w' with h5py in python

Tags: python, key, hdf5, h5py

I am attempting to display (and, later, rewrite) some data in an hdf5 file but I cannot see the key names or data after I open the file with the write 'w' argument.

This code works, successfully showing many keys:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('myfile', 'r') as f:
    print(list(f.keys()))
```

but code this doesn't, showing an empty list:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('myfile', 'w') as f:
    print(list(f.keys()))
```

and, weirdest of all, after running the second block (with 'w') the first block (with 'r') now shows an empty list as well!

The file itself appears unchanged; it's the exact same size and when I compare it to my backup copy with "diff", there is no difference (note: running the first block on my backup copy still works). I have no idea what the issue is and oddly couldn't find it discussed anywhere. I'm using python 3.7.

Comment: Opening with "w" truncates the file. I don't know why you see a different size but the file will be empty. That's why you see no keys. If you want to open it to add new data or overwrite parts of it, open it with mode "a"

Comment: Thank you! Checked the files again and they were empty, must have been looking at something incorrectly before. Opening them correctly now.

Comment: Opening a file in "w" mode creates a new "blank" file - effectively throwing away anything that was written to the same name (unless you are a wiz at file recovery).  Either open a file in 'r', or 'a' (if you want to add to it).  https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#opening-creating-files

Comment: As noted, mode='w' truncates the existing file (in other words, creates a new one). That's why you don't see the datasets (keys).